# BluetoothDevice how to know if a device is connected or disconnected

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list of bluetooth devices that I get from the bluetoothAdapter :

```kotlin
val bluetoothManager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(
        appContext,
        BluetoothManager::class.java
    ) as BluetoothManager
val bondedDevices = bluetoothManager.adapter.bondedDevices
```

After retrieving my list of bondedDevices, I tried to know the state of connection for all of them :

```
bondedDevices.forEach {
      when (val status = bluetoothManager.getConnectionState(it, BluetoothGatt.GATT)) {
                    BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED -> Log.d("DEBUG", "STATE_CONNECTED: $status")
                    BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTING -> Log.d("DEBUG", "STATE_CONNECTING: $status")
                    BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED -> Log.d(
                        "DEBUG",
                        "STATE_DISCONNECTED: $status"
                    )
                    BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTING -> Log.d(
                        "DEBUG",
                        "STATE_DISCONNECTING: $status"
                    )
                }
}
```

However, even if my device is connected to my phone, the status on the app will always be

```kotlin
BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED
```

### Questions

- Why the status is always BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED even if my device is connected to my phone?
- I saw some topics about retrieving bluetooth connection at startup but it seems to be possible only with a listener, is that the only way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query whether there is a Bluetooth connection in general. You need to know for which profile/service you want to know the connection status. Your code queries for a `GATT` connection which obviously does not exist. There are other profiles/services that your device could be connected to. See for example [BluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#getProfileConnectionState(int))

The second approach is to wait for events when lower layer Bluetooth connections are established or disconnected. As you mention, this is only possible with a `listener` and only for the time your application is running.

Comment: Thanks for you explanations,

Using BluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState() along with the HEADSET and A2DP profile seems to work !

Answer (score 0):

```
fun isBluetoothHeadsetConnected(): Boolean {
    val mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    return (mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled
        && mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothHeadset.HEADSET) == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED)
}
```

Bluetooth connection is mandatory for this
you'll need Bluetooth permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```